# Getting details of company which are managed by user - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm using [linkedin-oauth2](https://github.com/emorikawa/linkedin-oauth2) gem to implement LinkedIn login and getting details in my ruby on rails application. 
I'm trying to get the pages managed by the user. IN javascript SDK I could find it like this:

`IN.API.Raw("/companies?format=json&is-company-admin=true")`

But i could not find any documentation for the same when using ruby on rails.

Is there any way by which this is doable using this gem?

Comment: That's really not a lot to go on. Have you read the documentation more thoroughly?

Comment: @all_companies = api.company(is_admin: 'true').all , got it after trial and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer after lot of trial and error.

`@all_companies = api.company(is_admin: 'true').all`

This will return an array of objects with the id and name of all the companies manages by the user.